# Interstitial Ads frequency

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

I have an app that requires user to flip the pages to see next content and I want to show the interstitial ad for every pages turned. At the moment I attached one interstitial ad on the flipping pages, and say every 10 pages the ad showing.

But so far, only once appear, but the next 10th pages doesn't showing the ad again.

Can anyone help?

Comment: After the first add appears, reload the ad before showing again : interstitial.loadAd(adRequest); interstitial.show()

Comment: i did that, but the next ad never show up. and do we need to build the ads again => AdRequest adReq = new AdRequest.Builder().build() ?

Comment: Yes yodann you need to request the ad again. And maybe you can try it with another Ad unit ID ( creating within your app from admob UI) so that you know which placement is more effective for you.